# How can I use ActiveX in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, activex

In my project, I need  a usbkey to login. The interface of usbkey is Activex. 
In jquery way, the code just like below:

```
<html>
     <object style='display:none' 
      classid='clsid:28540C7-D724-4156-9E42-12BD' 
      codebase='Active/RaActive.CAB#version==-1,-1,-1,-1'  
      id='Ctrl'></object>
     <scrpit>
       $(document).ready(function() {
        Ctrl.initUxtApi();
       }
     </scrpit>
</html>
```

how can i change it to reactjs way?
The following code is my react way, but i think it is not a good method .

```
class USBKey extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
 const Ctrl = document.getElementById('Ctrl');
 console.log(Ctrl);
 let loginflag = -1;
 loginflag = Ctrl.initUxtApi();
 console.log(loginflag);
}

activeX ()
{
  return {__html: '<object style=\'display:none\' 
 classid=\'clsid:1221012-212-4156-9E42-121212\' ' +
'codebase= \'/RaActive.CAB#version==-1,-1,-1,-1\' ' +
' id=\'Ctrl\'></object>'}
};

render() {
 return (
  < div >
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.activeX()} />
  </ div >
);}
}
```

I will read a certification from UsbKey and send it to cloud.
just like this:
   `Ctrl.readCert();`

Comment: My English is poor , if you can correct my expression! please help me , I will appriceate it !

Comment: Can you show some of your react code or what you are trying to do?

Comment: I will read a certification from UsbKey through ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I don't work with ActiveX, but I believe you can do something like:

**index.html**

```
// outside of React
// leave this as is, it doesn't need to be inside react to use it 
// in react
<object style='display:none' 
  classid='clsid:28540C7-D724-4156-9E42-12BD' 
  codebase='Active/RaActive.CAB#version==-1,-1,-1,-1'  
  id='Ctrl'></object>

// Your react mount point
<div id="app"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
class USBKey extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { loginFlag: -1 };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const Ctrl = document.getElementById('Ctrl');
        this.setState({
            loginFlag: Ctrl.initUxtApi(),
        });        
    }

    render() {
        return <div>{this.state.loginFlag}</div>
    }
}
```